# Passing parameter to event handler giving errors

Tags: c#, event-handling, action, eventhandler

I have a class `Account`. In that I add an action called `Activation` and attach an event handler to it.

This is the code:

```
public class Account 
{
     public event Action Activation;

     public Account()
     {
          this.Activation += SendActivationEvent;
     }

     private void SendActivationEvent()
     {
           //do something here
     }
}
```

This is working fine. Now I want to add a parameter to the `SendActivationEvent` method. I have tried like this:

```
 string sourceID = String.Empty;
 this.Activation += SendActivationEvent(sourceID);

 private void SendActivationEvent(string sourceID)
 {
     //do something here
 }
```

It gives error at `SendActivationEvent(sourceID)` that

> Cannot implicitly convert type Void to System.Action

What can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `Action` doesn't accept parameters. Use `Action<T>` (`Action<String>` in your case) instead:

```
public class Account 
{
  // Note "String"
  public event Action<String> Activation;

  public Account()
  {
     // Assign method i.e. "SendActivationEvent", 
     // not method's result SendActivationEvent(sourceID)
     this.Activation += SendActivationEvent;
  }

  private void SendActivationEvent(string sourceID)
  {
     //TODO: do something here
  }
}
```